# Get posted values from dynamically added controls in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form in which i'm dynamically addding controls through jQuery. I need to access the values in those controls (textboxes) when posting back the form to the server. I'm sure this is a trivial problem but i just can't get my head around it.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When adding a multiple controls to the page, give them all the same `name` attribute so you can do the following in your action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string[] items)
{
     // items will contain all the values in the text boxes
    return View();
}
```

So your HTML would like like this

```
<input type="text" name="items" />
<input type="text" name="items" />
<input type="text" name="items" />
<input type="text" name="items" />
<input type="text" name="items" />
<input type="text" name="items" />
```